# Show UIPicker AND keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, keyboard, uipickerview

My requirements demand I show a numeric `UIPickerView` at the same time as the `keyboard`. The numeric picker I created does not appear right now when I click in the text field, although the keyboard does. And when I click on the row in the table, there is no  cursor in the text field, but the picker appears.

When the user clicks on the `textfield`, the picker should be displayed and the `keyboard` should also be displayed. Both at the same time. There are three prototype rows: a data row,  a date picker row and a numeric picker row. The numeric picker needs to also allow text entry from the software `keyboard`.

`hideExistingPickerBelowIndexPath` merely adds a new row of the picker type and adds a temporary row to the data.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        WCHistoryItem *anItem = [self getAnItemFromIndexPath:indexPath];
        if ([anItem.type isEqualToString:kDate] || [anItem.type isEqualToString:kNumeric]) {                

            if (_isPickerVisible != NO)
            {
                [self hideExistingPickerBelowIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.pickerIndexPath.row-1 inSection:self.pickerIndexPath.section]];
            }
            [self showNewPickerAtIndex:indexPath];
        } else {
            if (_isPickerVisible == YES) {
                [self hideExistingPickerBelowIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.pickerIndexPath.row-1 inSection:self.pickerIndexPath.section]];
            }
        }
    }
}

-(IBAction)didBeginEditingNumericField:(UITextField*)sender
{
    WCHistoryItem *anItem = [self getAnItemFromUIView:sender];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self getAnIndexPathFromUIView:sender];

    if (_isPickerVisible == NO)
    {
        //make a date cell
        [self showNewPickerAtIndex:indexPath];

    } else {
        [self hideExistingPickerBelowIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.pickerIndexPath.row-1 inSection:self.pickerIndexPath.section]];

        [self showNewPickerAtIndex:indexPath];            
    }
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)sender;
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

We need to show both the picker and a cursor in a text field with the software keyboard. Both of these at the same time. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

So what you describe is a slew of requirements. The project [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60414145/Picker.zip) demonstrates that you can have an active Picker and an active textField with the keyboard showing. So the core functionality that you want is provided by the system.

Animating the picker into the view should work while the keyboard is showing, and as the demo project shows, you can tap text into the textField and spin the picker.

It often really helps to spin up a really simple demo project to test something out, to be sure you have it right, before trying to integrate it into a complex project.

Comment: Thanks for your response! There is really only one requirement: a picker control and a keyboard that both appear at the same time and can both be used by the user to set the value. I'm evaluating the project you shared to see if it can be modified to do what I need.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. I cannot figure out why I can dynamically display a picker but not the software keyboard, or display a keyboard but not the picker.

Comment: Right - so you have some other issue. Your task is complex, and you need to break it into simpler pieces, and get each to work. Your original question here was getting the two views to work together, which I showed works now. So take that demo project, make the primary view a tableView, add the textField to a cell, then try again. If you try to "force" your current complex project to work you will probably spend way more time on this than you need. Since the Keyboard is actually in a window overlaid over the window with your views, trying to add new views then might not work properly.